# Open JMeter GUI mode without windows shell console

Tags: jmeter, windows-console

How to open JMeter GUI mode without windows shell console?

I'm running `jmeter.bat` and windows shell console stays open on top of JMeter GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jmeterw.cmd](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) instead of `jmeter.bat`

> run JMeter without the windows shell console (in GUI mode by default)